# Comparing objects between 2 arrays in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to figure the best way to do this, given that there will be a lot of data and I don't want to have giant loops hogging up resources. I have a lot of regular javascript/jquery experience, but am new to Angular and want to do it with Angularjs best practices.

I have a list of `items` and users can "favorite" them. When viewing all `items`, I'd like to show the ones that favorited by marking them with an indicator. Both `items` and `favorites` are in separate tables and returned as JSON with different IDs.

JS:

```
$scope.favorites = [];//$http.get of JSON file
$scope.items = [];//$http.get of JSON file

$scope.isFavorite = function(itemId) {
    var len = $scope.favorites. !== 'undefined' ? $scope.favorites.length : 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if($scope.favorites[i].id === itemId) {
            return true;
        }
    }
};
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <i ng-class="isFavorite(item.id) ? 'icon-bookmark' : 'icon-bookmark-empty'"></i>
</div>
```

I have a couple other checks for "`isFavorite`" so I'm trying to figure the best way to compare the 2 without checking every time in a loop. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most optimal way I can think of would be to modify the $scope.items array once the favourites http request has returned it's data, and set a 'favourite' boolean property on each item.

That way, your isFavourite method will not trigger on each digest cycle. For example:

```
var promises = [$http.get('/items'), $http.get('/favourites')];

$q.all(promises).then(function (resultsArray) {

    $scope.items = resultsArray[0];
    var favourites = resultsArray[1];

    $scope.items.forEach(function (item) {
        var matches = favourites.filter(function (f) {
                return f.id === item.id;
            });
        item.favourite = matches.length ? true : false;
    });

});
```

It's also worth bearing in mind that you probably want to wrap both http requests in a $q.all method so that you can fire a single callback once both http requests have finished.

EDIT: updated to show full code with $q.all implementation

Comment: if both arrays are returned from a server req, how can you be sure items is populated here?

Comment: As stated in my answer, you have to wrap the server requests in a $q.all method. For example $q.all([$http.get('/items'), $http.get('/favourites')]).then(function (resultsArray) { console.log(resultsArray); });

Comment: fair enough but this implementation wont work... not trolling you just stating...

Comment: It will work - because when you use $q.all, the callback only fires when both http requests have fully completed. This means that both items and favourites will be available.

Comment: this method _did_ work and was faster than my method. thanks for your help!